# Formula for conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be R.V.s and $\mathcal {H}$ be a sigma algebra defined on $\Omega$.

I know that $$\mathbb{E}(X|Y\in A)=\frac{\mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{1}_A)}{\mathbb{P}(Y\in A)}$$

And more generally

$$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal {H})=\sum_{B \in \mathcal {H}} \frac{\mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{1}_B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}1_B$$

Can someone explain why those formulas are in fact correct and how can I derive them? Both in simplistic case and in more general, formal way.

Comment: The second formula is only valid when $\mathcal H$ is generated by a(n at most countable) partition into events of positive probability.

Comment: oh, you're right. Of course.